# SQL Formatting issue when converting varchar to date 103

Tags: sql

I have a date field I pull in from excel as a varchar type and I currently convert it using this line:

```
convert(date,[Appt Date],103) as [Appt date]
```

this works but the result is a date in the following format:

YYYY/MM/DD

According to other sites the 103 format at the end of the line should convert this varchar to UK formatting ( DD/MM/YYYY ).

Can anyone advise why this is not happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MSSQL server store dates in `YYYY/MM/DD`. You can only change the language on the whole server, not individual databases.

```
set language 'british english'
```

run this first before inserting.

or another alternative is to use **[`SET DATEFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx)** (*from MSDN*)

```
declare @dates table (orig varchar(50) ,parsed datetime)

SET DATEFORMAT ydm;

insert into @dates
select '2008-09-01','2008-09-01'

SET DATEFORMAT ymd;
insert into @dates
select '2008-09-01','2008-09-01'

select * from @dates
```

<strike>It should be `VARCHAR` not `DATE`</strike>

```
SELECT convert(VARCHAR(20),[Appt Date],103) as [Appt date]
```

Comment: Perfect thank you! I removed the convert part and set the language as you said.